# Hide url and redirection implications for AJAX POST?

Tags: php, ajax, post, obfuscation, redirect

I'm creating a website with php backend. I have a directory called `/inc/` which contains php include files that get included when generating html webpages.

If a user tries to request any files in the `/inc/` directory (by url in their browser, for example), I've made it so they get redirected to the home page. I did this in an attempt to ensure that none of these files get called externally.

I have need to call one of these files via **jQuery POST** request.

Here is my question:

1) Can I somehow hide the url of the file requested in the POST?

2) Will a POST to a file in the `/inc/` folder via jQuery fail, since external requests for files in the /inc/ folder get redirected to the home page? Or does the server make a distinction between POST requests, and other types of requests?

3) (OPTIONAL) How can I ensure that the POST request is done "legitimately", as opposed to a bot trying to crash my server by issuing thousands of simultaneous post requests?

Comment: Why actually you need to hide files in `/inc` folder?

Comment: Because they aren't meant to be accessible as webpages. They are utility files to be included in other files, and I only want those files to be able to request them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Not without using a link somewhere, somehow. Remind yourself that jQuery / Ajax / XHTTPRquests / Xm... anything pointing outwards *has to point outwards*. There will always be an url, and it will always be traceable.

Options to make sure your url is less traceable

1. Create a page for your javascript calls (hides away, but doesn't really do anything)
2. Edit .htaccess options and use it to process javascript requests
3. Edit .htaccess options and a php page for server-side processing of javascript

**I'll be going over option 3**

Example (includes 2.!)

```
#Checks if the request is made within the domain
#Edit these to your domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^.*domain\.com [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^.*domain\.com.*$ [NC]

#Pretends the requested page isn't there
RewriteRule \.(html|php|api.key)$ /error/404 [L]

#Set a key to your 'hidden' url
#Since this is server-based, the client won't be able to get it
#This will set the environment variable when a request is made to
#www.yourwebsite.com/the folder this .htaccess is in/request_php_script
SetEnvIf Request_URI "request_php_script" SOMEKINDOFenvironmentNAME=http://yourlink.com

#Alternatively set Env in case your apache doesn't support it
#I use both
SetEnv SOMEKINDOFNAME request_php_script

#This will send the requester to the script you want when they call
#www.yourwebsite.com/the folder this .htaccess is in/request_php_script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} request_php_script$ [NC]
#if you don' want a php script to handle javascript and benefit the full url obfuscation, write the following instead
#RewriteRule ^.*$ /adirectscript.php [L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /aredirectscript.php [L]

#and yes this can be made shorter, but this works best if folders and keys in your ENV are similar in some extend
```

In this case could call a php script that redirects you to the right page, but if everything is internal, then I don't see the reason why you would hide away the url to your scripts. If you have set the .htaccess as shown, only your page can access it. Users and external sources aren't able to reach it, as they'll be redirected.

If your scripts refer to an external API key however, then this might be useful, and you could call the redirect script

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents(getEnv("SOMEKINDOFNAME"));
?>
```

Now when this script is called, it'll return your contents. If you want to load in pages, you can call something described like here this instead

[getting a webpage content using Php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17697753/getting-a-webpage-content-using-php)

To make full use of this, you have to set your jQuery POST method to POST at www.yourwebsite.com **/the folder this .htaccess is in/request_php_script.php**

3. If 1 and 2 are done properly, like above, you shouldn't have to worry from bots from the outside trying to reach your .php scripts

**Sidenote**:
You can skip the extra php script, but you'll be traceable in the .har files. Which means that in the end, your url is still reachable somewhere. Using the extra php script (give it query parameters for convenience) will obfuscate the url enough to make it dead hard to find. I've used this way to hide away requests to an external API key

**TLDR**:

- set .htaccess server environment variable for page
- set .htaccess rewrite condition to page to be redirected to page if

  - originally from my page
  - called by script
- set javascript to call specified page

> **Medium 'secure'**
>
> cannot be found in script
>
> cannot be traced back without saving har files

- create php file to return page contents
- set .htaccess to point to php instead of page

> **Highly 'secure'**
>
> cannot be found in script
>
> cannot be traced back, even when saving har files

Answer (score 0):

1) No.

2) Depends on how you handle redirects, best way is to try and see.

3) Not an easy task in general. Simple approach is to detect same client and limit request rate. No way to detect a bot in general only by request data.

As for your last comment, you can restrict access to thouse files with .htaccess without need for redirects. However you still won't be able to get them with AJAX. The only real reason to hide something is if there is some sensitive information inside like, passwords, logins, something like that. Overwise it's doesn't really matter, nobody is interested in some hidden utulity files.

Comment: For p. 2) still same, test and see. I guress it will also redirect, but I'm not sure.