# getting a webpage content using Php

Tags: php, html

Now this I know is relatively simple to do, but i want to use a form to get the URLs to use in this. I started using file_get_contents but then i switched to fopen.

```
    <?php

  $marki = fopen($page, "rb");
  $page = $_GET['page'];


  echo $marki;

  ?>

<html>
  <body>
    <form method="get" action="index.php">
      <input type="text" name="page">
      <input type="submit" value="grade">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

this is the code i have used so far, I think it the answer could still lie with using file_get_contents but it wont get the page contents as it keeps pointing the get contents to files stored in my server which is not what I am aiming for.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `$page` before `$marki`, like -

```
$page = $_GET['page'];
$marki = fopen($page, "rb");
```

Answer (score 0):

When you were using 'file_get_contents' did you put 'http://' in front of the url? If you didn't, it will try and find the url on your own server. See below :

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
echo $homepage;
?>
```

And the official documentation [PHP:file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can always try cURL too. I personally just learned how to do it yesterday, and it's about 6x faster than `file_get_contents`.

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "url");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, TRUE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

When you `echo $output`, it will return the page it got. Can also do a lot more with it.

Comment: Can you provide some documentation about that speed benchmark?